# Get values from Django data base

Tags: python, html, django

I need to get the data from a form in a Django database. The problem when I use `.cleaned_data['name']` I am getting an attribute error

> 'SnippetForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'.

when I tried passing through if `old_form.is_valid()`, the if is False.

With my code, I can get the HTML info, but I can not parser it with .clean_data.

Basically I don't want to create a regex and parse the html, I am looking for some Django Method that can help.

Html code got from Django:

```html
<tr><th><label for="id_name">Name:</label></th><td><input type="text" name="name" value="Ariel" maxlength="100" id="id_name"></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_email">Email:</label></th><td><input type="email" name="email" value="as@onsemi.com" maxlength="254" id="id_email"></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_subject">Subject:</label></th><td><input type="text" name="subject" value="Test" maxlength="100" id="id_subject"></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_body">Body:</label></th><td><textarea name="body" cols="40" rows="10" id="id_body">
This is a test</textarea></td></tr>
```

In my views.py

```py
def data_detail (request, request_id):

    data_detail_django =  get_object_or_404(Snippet, pk=request_id)
    if request.method == "POST": #Also, it is not going throu this if... 
        old_form = SnippetForm(request.POST, instance=data_detail_django)

    else: #The old_form is the html output and is get it with this 
        old_form = SnippetForm(instance=data_detail_django)


    if old_form.is_valid():
        print(old_form.cleaned_data['name'])

    return HttpResponse("contact view")
```

In my models

```py
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Snippet(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True, null=True)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    body = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

in my form.py

```py
from django import forms
from .models import Snippet


class SnippetForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Snippet
        fields = ('name', 'email','subject', 'body')
```

Comment: Move your check for validity inside your if conditional for POST. In addition, you put the html code that the django rendered, it is much better to show your actual html code and not the html that django generated. For example, I have no idea if you have a csrf token.

Comment: use `cleaned_data.get('name')`

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your reply, I know what you mean.. I am posting the data succefully, now I wanted to get the data out from the database. Reding on weeking I found the solution by myself I only need to do an 
```python 
def data_detail (request, request_id):
  data_dbs =  Snippet.objects.get(pk= request_id)
  data_out = {'data_dbs': data_dbs} #This dict will render the html, data_out is just a reference to the dict, that name is not a imput in the html
  return render(request, 'form_app/detail.html', data_out )
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was: Uning .objects.get(pk = vaule)

```py
def data_detail (request, request_id):
    data_dbs =  Snippet.objects.get(pk= request_id)
    data_out = {'data_dbs': data_dbs} 
    return render(request, 'form_app/detail.html', data_out )
```

and in the html to render:

```html
{% extends 'form_app/base.html' %}

{% block main_content %}

{% if data_dbs %} 

      <p>Name: {{data_dbs.name}}</p>
      <p>Email: {{data_dbs.email}}</p>
      <p>Subject: {{data_dbs.subject}}</p>
      <p>Body: {{data_dbs.body}}</p>

{% else %}

  <p> No data</p>

{% endif %}


<a href = '/data'><b>See Form</b></a></li>
{% endblock %}
```